# Starting with esm modules in node.js giving error: Cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I'm starting code with `node src/index.js` (starting with `--experimental-modules` flag giving same error). 
In package.json `type: "module"`

My code: `index.js`

```js
import Client from './structures/CalidiumClient';
import moment from 'moment';
const bot = new Client();
moment.locale('ru');
bot.start();
```

Error:

```
(node:8560) ExperimentalWarning: The ESM module loader is experimental.
internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:61
  let url = moduleWrapResolve(specifier, parentURL);
            ^

Error: Cannot find module D:\ÐÐ¾ÑÐºÑÑ\Calidium\src\structures\CalidiumClient imported from D:\ÐÐ¾ÑÐºÑÑ\Calidium\src\index.js
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:61:13)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:85:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:191:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:42:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:41:36) {
  code: 'ERR_MODULE_NOT_FOUND'
}
```

**UPD**: i'm using node.js v13.11.0

Comment: Did you name your folder using totally English? Seems like the path name has turn into sth weird

Comment: no but before it worked fine and i'm not sure this is problem